# Whitespaces in cvs modules file

Tags: cvs

I'm trying to add some files with whitespaces to my CVS Modules file, but can't figure out how to write its name.

tried using ", ', \", \'.
nothing worked.

how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have whitespace in the module name. The parser for modules files is as [simple as it gets](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/cvs/ccvs/src/myndbm.c?revision=1.39&view=markup) and will stop at the first whitespace to make the module name:

```
while (*vp && !isspace ((unsigned char) *vp))
    vp++;
if (*vp)
    *vp++ = '\0';       /* NULL terminate the key */
p->type = NDBMNODE;
p->key = xstrdup (kp);
```